# How to make the UITextView keyboard don't dismiss by tapping_Swift

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uitextview

I have a problem about the keyboard.
If I want to keep showing keyboard when I tap, and what should I do.
I also mark the addObserver function "*keyboardWillHide*", but the keyboard also dismiss.
Thanks.

This is code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name:.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
//NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name:.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}

override func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    super.keyboardWillShow(notification: notification)

    if let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo as NSDictionary? {
        if let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.value(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as? NSValue {
            keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height
        }
    }
    setUserMode(mode: .keyboard)
    updateViewFrame()
}

override func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    keyboardHeight = 0
    updateViewFrame()
}

func updateViewFrame() {
    var diffHeight:CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    if let nav = navigationController {
        diffHeight += nav.navigationBar.height
    }
    let newFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: diffHeight, width: ScreenWidth, height: ScreenHeight-keyboardHeight-diffHeight)

    if view.frame.equalTo(newFrame) == false  {
        view.frame = newFrame
        self.tableView.frame = newFrame
    }
}
```

Image here:

[image]

Comment: If you want the keyboard to be visible after the tap - don't resign the first responder

Comment: But I seem I don't call the resignFirstResponse()

Answer (score 0):

Just call :

```
YourTextView.keyboardDismissMode = .none
```

Comment: Though this answer might or might not provide a solution to the issue, please always ad some explanation to your answer as it will help people that has similar problems understand the solution.